# playing sound in unity when detect multiple image target

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

i detect more than one image target in #unity when i detect target i play a sound that pronounce the image target name. if i detect one target it play the sound loud but when detect multiple target it play one of sound loud and play the others very low or does not play them.
please i want specific way to do this in tutorial or explain that in your answer .

using UnityEngine;

```
public class SoundPlay: MonoBehaviour,ITrackableEventHandler
{
#region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
public AudioClip sound;
#endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



#region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

void Start()
{
    mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
    if (mTrackableBehaviour)
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
    }
}

#endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



#region PUBLIC_METHODS

/// <summary>
/// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
/// tracking state changes.
/// </summary>
public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
                                TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
    {
        OnTrackingFound();
    }
    else
    {
        OnTrackingLost();
    }
}

#endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS



#region PRIVATE_METHODS


private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // Enable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    // Enable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = true;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
    GetComponentInChildren<fiveSound>().Play();
}


private void OnTrackingLost()
{
    Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
    Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

    // Disable rendering:
    foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    // Disable colliders:
    foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
    {
        component.enabled = false;
    }

    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
}


 public void Play(){
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sound, transform.position);
}
#endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Is 3D sound checked?

If it is then uncheck. Let me know how you get on!

^._.^

Answer (score -1):

```
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;

public class SoundPlay: MonoBehaviour,ITrackableEventHandler
{
    #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

    private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;
    public AudioClip sound;
    #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES



    #region UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS

    void Start()
    {
        mTrackableBehaviour = GetComponent<TrackableBehaviour>();
        if (mTrackableBehaviour)
        {
            mTrackableBehaviour.RegisterTrackableEventHandler(this);
        }
    }

    #endregion // UNTIY_MONOBEHAVIOUR_METHODS



    #region PUBLIC_METHODS

    /// <summary>
    /// Implementation of the ITrackableEventHandler function called when the
    /// tracking state changes.
    /// </summary>
    public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
        TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
        TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
    {
        if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
            newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED)
        {
            OnTrackingFound();
        }
        else
        {
            OnTrackingLost();
        }
    }

    #endregion // PUBLIC_METHODS



    #region PRIVATE_METHODS


    private void OnTrackingFound()
    {
        Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

        // Enable rendering:
        foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = true;
        }

        // Enable colliders:
        foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = true;
        }

        Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
        GetComponentInChildren<AudioSource>().Play();
    }


    private void OnTrackingLost()
    {
        Renderer[] rendererComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Renderer>(true);
        Collider[] colliderComponents = GetComponentsInChildren<Collider>(true);

        // Disable rendering:
        foreach (Renderer component in rendererComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }

        // Disable colliders:
        foreach (Collider component in colliderComponents)
        {
            component.enabled = false;
        }

        Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
    }


    public void Play(){
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(sound, transform.position);
    }
    #endregion // PRIVATE_METHODS
}
```

Comment: While the code in your answer may contain the correct information to solve the OP's question - users will find it much easier to understand that information if you include an explanation.